# find/grep command that displays filename and java package

Tags: linux, shell, grep, find

Basically I want to find a string in only java files present in a folder(recursively) and want to display their filepath as well as the "package" of the corresponding java file that contains the string.

```
find . -name '*.java' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l 'SRO'
```

The command that I wrote above searches for the string 'SRO' and prints the filepath of those files.

Kindly suggest shell script commands for the same.

Comment: 1. Show your attempt. 2. Provide some sample input/output.

Comment: That is a shell script...

Comment: Can you clarify `want to display their filepath as well as the "package"` requirement.

Comment: @CDahn the answer that you gave below gives me the output that I want. Thanks a lot for that. Can you suggest what else should I add in the script below to print the filename as well. For simply print <file-name>.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
for file in `find -name "*.java"`
do
    if [ "`grep SRO $file`" != "" ]
    then
        echo "Path: `dirname $file`"
        echo "Package: `grep package $file`"
    fi
done
```

Comment: the answer that you gave above gives me the output that I want. Thanks a lot for that. Can you suggest what else should I add in the script below to print the filename as well. For simply print <file-name>.java. Also could you share a link from where I could learn all this so that I can make some of these on my own in future. :)

Comment: There is numerous issues with this answer. `find` command's output should not be used in for loop like this. What if filenames have space or new lines? `grep` has much better `-q` option for this condition.

Comment: Just add echo 'basename $file". I also used Google to search for "learn bash scripting" and got several reasonable looking resources, including http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html

Comment: @anub I hope the filenames don't have newlines... I believe you could also add "unset IFS" to handle whitespace correctly.

Comment: None of them are enough to handle spaces/newlines. Anyway you can learn more about these cases from other answers on SO.